# How to insert cells in existing rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

[image]I am new to jquery and javascript.Here if the checkbox is selected in the first table ,I am adding the rows to the second table but I need some extra cells also in the same row. I am trying like this. It duplicates the cells everytime. I have included the screenshot of the output. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
 function table2()
{
$('#one').on("click", function(){
    $('#one tbody input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two");
  $('#two tr').append('<td>  </td>','<td> </td>','<td> </td>', '<td> </td>','<td> </td>','<td> </td>','<td> </td>','<td> </td>','<td> </td>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95uq7pz3/

Comment: Can you please post you HTML too?

Comment: Can you provide more code and elaborate? I'm not sure what's going on or what you're trying to do.

Comment: kindly check the jsfiddle@VadimOvchinnikov

Comment: Now I have included the jsfiddle@LeeWise

Answer (score 1):

So it's pretty simple, you just need to pass through every row (tr) and append a td to it.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('table').find('tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>_0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>_1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button>Add a column</button>
```

Comment: I am trying to add like this. But again it duplicates. Its adding the cells everytime like the screenshot I have included before.                      function table2()
{
$('#one').on("click", function(){
        $('#one tbody input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two");
add();
}); 
}
                                                                                                        function add()
{
$('#two').find('tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
  });
}

Comment: Alright, it ok if it's not exactly it. Could you then please be more specific about the result you'd like to achieve?

Comment: yeah.. The above code is working. But its replicating each and everytime.I am adding the row from table1(contains 3 columns) to table2 (contains 3 columns)+(extra 10 columns)if the checkbox is selected. Inaddition to that i need some cells for that 13 columns... You can see my jsfiddle also for clear understanding.@kiwad

Comment: You need to clean your fiddle cause theres a login box which seems not working properly and it's not really related to the question. In order to give the community a will to help you, you have to make it concise and stripped from unnecessary code (thanks ;) ). For what I understand, you need to put another table's row inside another one. Is that it? If yes, you'll have to replicate all the rows unless rows always follow the same logic. Again, I may misundertood you, thats why I ask you to clean your code. Cya :)